# Getting null value while i call one servlet from other , using both case session and form submit

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have two servlets 1)qz.java and 2)logout.java  i want to get email from qz to logout , this is my actual problem.

when i try to get email from login page to qz page by session it works fine , but when i want to send email from qz.java to logout.java it getting null value 
 Then i try different way , i add  and when i submit this code to logout i get email by String s=request.getPrameter("xyz"); but s returns null value . this code is of quiz application please give me proper answer.

Here is my code ...doget post of qz.ja

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    String val=(String) session.getAttribute("user1");
    String val1=(String) session.getAttribute("email");

    session.setAttribute("em", val1);

    PrintWriter pr=response.getWriter();

    String a="abcdefg";

    if(val==null) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.html");
    }else {

        //pr.println("");
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("./timer");
        rd.include(request, response);

        pr.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
                "<html>\r\n" + 
                "<head>\r\n" + 
                "   <title></title>\r\n" + 
                "   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->\r\n" + 
                "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<!-- jQuery library -->\r\n" + 
                "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->\r\n" + 
                "<script src=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>\r\n" + 
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n" + 
                "var idleTime = 0;\r\n" + 
                "$(document).ready(function () {\r\n" + 
                "    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.\r\n" + 
                "    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 600); \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.\r\n" + 
                "    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {\r\n" + 
                "        idleTime = 0;\r\n" + 
                "    });\r\n" + 
                "    $(this).keypress(function (e) {\r\n" + 
                "        idleTime = 0;\r\n" + 
                "    });\r\n" + 
                "});\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "function timerIncrement() {\r\n" + 
                "    idleTime = idleTime + 1;\r\n" + 
                "    if (idleTime > 6) { \r\n" + 
                "        window.location.href=\"login.html\";\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}\r\n" + 
                "</script>"+

                "</head>\r\n" + 
                "<body>\r\n" + 
                "<div id=\"u\" name=\"usern\">\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + "Welcome :"+val+
                "    </div>"+


                "<form action=\"logout\" id=\"logsub\">\r\n" + 

                "<div class=\"container\">\r\n" + "<div name=\"email\" value=\"tofik@gmail.com\">\r\n" + 
                        "           \r\n" + 
                        "</div>\r\n" + 
                        ""+
                "<label id=\"e\" name=\"abc\" value=\"abc\"> abc : </label>\r\n" + 


                "   <div class=\"row\">\r\n" + 
                "       <!-- Carousel -->\r\n" + 
                "       <div id=\"carousel-example-generic\" class=\"carousel slide\">\r\n" + 
                "           <!-- Indicators -->\r\n" + 
                "           \r\n" + 
                "           <!-- Wrapper for slides -->\r\n" + 
                "           <div class=\"carousel-inner\">\r\n" + 
                "               <div class=\"item active\">\r\n" + 
                "                   <!img src=\"http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg\" alt=\"First slide\">\r\n" + 
                "                    <!-- Static Header -->\r\n" + 
                "                    <div class=\"header-text hidden-xs\">\r\n" + 
                "                        <div class=\"col-md-12 text-center\">\r\n" + 
                "                            <div class=\"container\">\r\n" + 
                "<div class=\"col-sm-6\" style=\"margin-left:250px;margin-top:150px\">\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<div style=\"border:2px solid black;padding:10px;margin-top:20px\">\r\n" + 
                "                <h4 >What is 1+1 ?</h4>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "             \r\n" + 
                "               \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                  \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans1\" value=\"1\" >A : 1\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                       <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans1\" value=\"2\" >B : 2\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                       <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans1\" value=\"4\" >C : 4\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                  \r\n" + 
                "                   \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans1\" value=\"3\" >D : 3\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                       \r\n" + 
                "                       \r\n" + 
                "                    \r\n" + 
                "           \r\n" + 
                "               \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "     \r\n" + 
                "     </div>       \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                        </div>\r\n" + 
                "                    </div><!-- /header-text -->\r\n" + 
                "               </div>\r\n" + 
                "               <div class=\"item\">\r\n" + 
                "                   <!img src=\"http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg\" alt=\"Second slide\">\r\n" + 
                "                   <!-- Static Header -->\r\n" + 
                "                    <div class=\"header-text hidden-xs\">\r\n" + 
                "                        <div class=\"col-md-12 text-center\">\r\n" + 
                "                           <div class=\"container\">\r\n" + 
                "<div class=\"col-sm-6\" style=\"margin-left:250px;margin-top:150px\">\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<div style=\"border:2px solid black;padding:10px;margin-top:20px\">\r\n" + 
                "                <h4 >What is 4/2 ?</h4>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "             \r\n" + 
                "               \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                  \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans2\" value=\"3\" >A : 3\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                       <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans2\" value=\"5\" >B : 5\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                       <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans2\" value=\"2\" >C : 2\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                  \r\n" + 
                "                   \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans2\" value=\"6\" >D : 6\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                      \r\n" + 
                "                       \r\n" + 
                "                    \r\n" + 
                "           \r\n" + 
                "               \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "     \r\n" + 
                "     </div>       \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                        </div>\r\n" + 
                "                    </div><!-- /header-text -->\r\n" + 
                "               </div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "           <div class=\"item\">\r\n" + 
                "            <!img src=\"http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg\" alt=\"Second slide\">\r\n" + 
                "            <!-- Static Header -->\r\n" + 
                "                    <div class=\"header-text hidden-xs\">\r\n" + 
                "                        <div class=\"col-md-12 text-center\">\r\n" + 
                "                           <div class=\"container\">\r\n" + 
                "<div class=\"col-sm-6\" style=\"margin-left:250px;margin-top:150px\">\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<div style=\"border:2px solid black;padding:10px;margin-top:20px\">\r\n" + 
                "                <h4 >What is 5*2*1 ?</h4>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "             \r\n" + 
                "               \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                  \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                        <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans3\" value=\"11\" >A : 11\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "            <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans3\" value=\"3\" >B : 3\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "            <input type=\"radio\"  name=\"ans3\" value=\"2\" >C : 2\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "            \r\n" + 
                "                                         \r\n" + 
                "                        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans3\" value=\"10\" >D : 10\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "                   <br>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                      \r\n" + 
                "                 \r\n" + 
                "               \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "     \r\n" + 
                "     </div>       \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                        </div>\r\n" + 
                "                    </div><!-- /header-text -->\r\n" + 
                "          </div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "               <div class=\"item\">\r\n" + 
                "                   <!img src=\"http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg\" alt=\"Third slide\">\r\n" + 
                "                   <!-- Static Header -->\r\n" + 
                "                    <div class=\"header-text hidden-xs\">\r\n" + 
                "                        <div class=\"col-md-12 text-center\">\r\n" + 
                "                            <div class=\"container\">\r\n" + 
                "<div class=\"col-sm-6\" style=\"margin-left:250px;margin-top:150px\">\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<div style=\"border:2px solid black;padding:10px;margin-top:20px\">\r\n" + 
                "          \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "             \r\n" + 
                "                \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                  \r\n" + 
                "                        \r\n" + 
                "                      \r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<label id=\"e\" name=\"email\"> Mail ID :"+val1+" </label>"+
                "                       <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit1\" value=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">\r\n" + 
                "                       \r\n" + 
                "                    \r\n" + 
                "           \r\n" + 
                "                \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "     \r\n" + 
                "     </div>       \r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "                        </div>\r\n" + 
                "                    </div><!-- /header-text -->\r\n" + 
                "               </div>\r\n" + 
                "           </div>\r\n" + 
                "           <!-- Controls -->\r\n" + 
                "           <a class=\"left carousel-control\" href=\"#carousel-example-generic\" data-slide=\"prev\">\r\n" + 
                "               <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span>\r\n" + 
                "           </a>\r\n" + 
                "           <a class=\"right carousel-control\" href=\"#carousel-example-generic\" data-slide=\"next\">\r\n" + 
                "               <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>\r\n" + 
                "           </a>\r\n" + 
                "       </div><!-- /carousel -->\r\n" + 
                "   </div>\r\n" + 
                "</div>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "</form>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "</body>\r\n" + 
                "</html>");


        }


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //
            //doGet(request, response);

}
```

2)logout.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    //session.invalidate();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();

    //String s=(String) ses.getAttribute("email");
    PrintWriter pr1 = response.getWriter();
    String ans1=request.getParameter("ans1");
    String ans2=request.getParameter("ans2");
    String ans3=request.getParameter("ans3");
    String emailid=request.getParameter("email");
    String abc=request.getParameter("abc");
    System.out.println(emailid);
    //int a11=0;
    System.out.println(ans1);



    //pr1.println(s);
    int score=0;
    String a1="2",a2="2",a3="10";
    if(ans1.equals(a1)) {
        score=score+1;
        System.out.println("incremented");
    }
    if(ans2.equals(a2)) {
        score=score+1;
        System.out.println("incremented");
    }
    if(ans3.equals(a3)) {
        score=score+1;
        System.out.println("incremented");
    }
    String mar=""+score;
    //ses.setAttribute("marks", mar);
    doPost(request, response);
    pr1.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
            "<html>\r\n" + 
            "<head>\r\n" + 
            "   <title></title>\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "<!-- jQuery library -->\r\n" + 
            "<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->\r\n" + 
            "<script src=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
             "  <script>\r\n" + 
             "window.onload = function (){ UrFunction(); }\r\n" + 
             "\r\n" + 
             "function UrFunction()\r\n" + 
             "{\r\n" + 
             "  var x;\r\n" + 
             "  var r=confirm(\"Your Score is :"+mar+"\");\r\n" + 
             "  if (r==true)\r\n" + 
             "  {\r\n" + 
             //"    confirm(\"Wanna change Password?\");s\r\n" + 
             "      window.location.assign(\"login.html\")\r\n" + 
             "  }\r\n" + 
             "  else\r\n" + 
             "  {\r\n" + 
             "      x=\"You pressed Cancel!\";\r\n" + 
             "\r\n" + 
             "  }\r\n" + 
             "  \r\n" + 
             "}\r\n" + 
             "</script>"+
            "\r\n" + 
            "</head>\r\n" + 
            "<body>\r\n" + 
            " \r\n" + 
            ""+
            "\r\n" + 
            "</body>\r\n" + 
            "</html>\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "");
    //ans1="";      ans2="";        ans3=""; score=0;
    //response.sendRedirect("login.html");


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doGet(request, response);
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    String s1=(String) session.getAttribute("em");
    System.out.println("Email="+s1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making things very difficult for yourself. Why in the world would you want to write your html in your servlet? This is the reason why you cannot access the email parameter..

```
//pr.println("");
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("./timer");
    rd.include(request, response);

    pr.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" + 
            "<html>\r\n" + 
            "<head>\r\n" +
```

After the include you are just printing out html.

What you should do is all that html code you have in your first servlet, put in a JSP or HTML file!

Then use the first servlet to forward to that jsp/html file like so:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    String val=(String) session.getAttribute("user1");
    String val1=(String) session.getAttribute("email");

    session.setAttribute("em", val1);

    PrintWriter pr=response.getWriter();

    String a="abcdefg";

    if(val==null) {
           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");   
           rd.forward(request,response);  
        return;
    }else {
           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("somethingElse.html");   
           rd.forward(request,response);  

       }
    }
```

Then in your somethingElse.html (or JSP) file... you add that html code and submit the form from there. Only then will you be able to access the email variable from logout.